# Object Oriented Programming PHP using two different files

Tags: php, oop, authentication

So I'm trying to use OOP now to change things up, and I'm using two differen't files, so in one file (The directory is `Functions/login.class.php`) is all of the code for the login function, the code consists of this

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class Login { 

public function login($username, $password) {
    $CheckLogin = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
    $CheckLogin->execute(array($username, encrypt($username, $password));
    return $CheckLogin->rowCount();
}


public function encrypt($username, $password) {
return md5(sha1(md5($username.$password)));
}

}


?>
```

and my next file is in the main directory called `remoteapi.php`, and I'm trying to call the function and have it return the rowCount which will either be `0` or `1`

```
<?php
require('Functions/login.class.php');

$action = $_GET['action'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

if($action == 'login') {
    $output = new Login;
    echo $output->login($username, $password);
}   
?>
```

And here's the `config.php`

```
<?php
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";
$details = "mysql:dbname=NAME;host=localhost";
$database = new PDO($details, $user, $pass);
?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens at all, no errors, blank page.

Comment: you should get errors, since $database is undefined in your login method.

Comment: `$database` is not defined in the `login` function. You can't use global variables inside a function by default. Try putting `global $database;` at the top of the function, to make it available inside.

Comment: $database is inherited from the config.php that was required at the top of the page.

Comment: Please don't do that, using globals like that is terribly terrible.

Comment: Patrick, it isn't--the function doesn't know about `$database` until you tell it that it exists. See http://php.net/global

Comment: check your line $output->login($username,$password); and go to that function and echo '111'; exit; if it return something then check your query and your instance of the object is like that $output = new Login();

Comment: make your constructor function and include config file there

Comment: this is far far far from OOP... The fact you use some class here and there does not mean you are doing OOP... Try to build your application on some OOP (+MVC is a plus) framework and then You'll see what the OOP really is :-).

Comment: Well it still is OOP, just not OOP used at its most.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your class a little bit. You can create a constructor to pass the `$database` object and store it inside the class for instance.

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class Login { 

    private $database;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $CheckLogin = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
        $CheckLogin->execute(array($username, encrypt($username, $password));
        return $CheckLogin->rowCount();
    }

    public function encrypt($username, $password) {
        return md5(sha1(md5($username.$password)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this, now I know it's something in the class because the page goes blank when I do "require('login.class.php');"

Comment: Well the problem with your class was that you had no access to `$database`. If it still doesn't work then you probably would have to show us more files.

Comment: Here's whats inside of the `config.php` > I'll just edit the main post with config.php